# Find a cell (using VLookup) and use the cell location found in a range

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have simple data, with one column a daily incrementing date column, and the second column being a numeric value. I want to VLOOKUP the data for todays date (which I can do) and then get the average of this value plus the 7 days values before then as well.

Something a bit like:

```
=AVERAGE( VLOOKUP(today(),A2:B110,2,false)) : (VLOOKUP(today()-7,A2:B110,2,false))
```

But with the VLOOKUP returning the cell location rather than the data.

As with so many questions on here, I have searched, but I don't know the terms I am looking for and googling anything with VLOOKUP in the terms opens floodgates to questions that aren't quite what I'm asking. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your dates are in strictly increasing order, correct? In which case, assuming you're using Excel 2007 or later, you could use:

`=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B110,A2:A110,"<="&TODAY(),A2:A110,">="&TODAY()-7)`

This INDEX formula will also work, though is not as efficient:

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(B2:B110,MATCH(TODAY(),A2:A110,0)):INDEX(B2:B110,MATCH(TODAY(),A2:A110,0)-7))`

Regards

Comment: Many thanks! I'm actually using Google Sheets but figured the response would be interchangeable, or at least give me the terms I would need to search for the correct functions. The first solution worked for me, thank you! The second actually gave me an error but it may well be GSheets specific. Either way though, the 1st solution worked a treat to thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! And good job you were able to translate it into the required Google Sheets equivalent, as I certainly couldn't!!

Comment: No translation needed, copy and paste :)